# Label affects legend symbols in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with two different variables - city and town

When I plot them and add two regression lines with `stat_smooth`, the legend symbols do not appear correctly (they appear as two 'a's):

```
ggplot(metrics, aes(x=popDensity, y= TPB, color = factor(type))) + geom_point() +theme_minimal() + stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  geom_label_repel(aes(label= rownames(metrics)), size=3) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", color="#666666", face="bold", size=12)) +
  labs(x = expression(paste( "density ", km^{2})), y = expression(paste("rating[![enter image description here][1]][1]")))+
  theme(legend.position="top", legend.direction="horizontal")
```

This is the result: [image]

However, when I remove the `geom_label_repel` function, I get the legend symbols I need - but of course the labels do not appear.

```
ggplot(metrics, aes(x=popDensity, y= TPB, color = factor(type))) + geom_point() +theme_minimal() + stat_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE) +
  #geom_label_repel(aes(label= rownames(metrics)), size=3) +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "Trebuchet MS", color="#666666", face="bold", size=12)) +
  labs(x = expression(paste( "density ", km^{2})), y = expression(paste("rating")))+
  theme(legend.position="top", legend.direction="horizontal")
```

[image]

Why does this happen and is there a known workaround for this issue?  Additionally, is there a way to manually change the title of the legend title? I have tried using `+ theme(legend.title = "title"`) but get the error :

```
Error in (function (el, elname)  : 
  Element legend.title must be a element_text object.
```

the sample data:

```
> dput(metrics)
structure(list(popDensity = c(4308, 27812, 4447, 5334, 4662, 
2890, 24623, 5847, 1689, 481, 4100), TPB = c(1, 0.5, 1, 1.3, 
0.8, 4, 0.2, 0.7, 5, 4, 2), type = c("City", "City", "City", 
"City", "City", "City", "Town", "Town", "Town", "Town", "Town"
)), .Names = c("popDensity", "TPB", "type"), row.names = c("City1", 
"City2", "City3", "City4", "City5", "City6", "Town1", "Town2", 
"Town3", "Town4", "Town5"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `show.legend = FALSE` within your `geom_label_repel` call.  The `a's` seem to be the standard legend for the labels, which overrides the `geom_point` that uses the same colours.

Comment: Thanks - how should one change the title of the legend from `factor(type)` to something else?

Comment: Then I get `Error in f(...) : argument "values" is missing, with no default`

Comment: Sorry - this should work `+ scale_colour_discrete(name="something else")`.  I always have trouble with colour scales!